# Корректный вывод с lambda

Tags: python

Скажите, как можно с помощью lambda указать, по какому именно условию мы должны выводить число.

К примеру есть список чисел и контрольное число:

Нужно вывести сумму попарных элементов, сумма которых меньше контрольного числа по возрастанию, а также сами эти числа также в порядке возрастания

```
listt = [10, 7, 2, 12, 76, 100, 324]
control_number = 30

# вывести последовательно сумму двух элементов, если эта сумма меньше контрольного числа
# Для первых двух чисел: 10 + 7 = 17, a 17 < 30, значит число 17 удовлетворяет условию.
# 7 + 2 = 9, a 9 < 30, 9 удовлетворяет
# 2 + 12 = 14, a 14 < 30, 14 удовлетворяет условию
# 12 + 76 = 88, a 88 > 30, 88 не удовлетворяет условию
# Нужно вывести сумму попарных элементов, сумма которых меньше контрольного числа по возрастанию, а также сами эти числа также в порядке возрастания:
# 9 14 17
# 2 7 10 12
```

Вывод:

9 14 17

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы выводилось не подряд 17 9 14, а по возрастанию?

**P.S. Без использования списка и метода списков, чисто с лямбда**

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/python-sorting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без методов списка, но со списком.

Используем `heapq heappush/heappop`:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

listt = [10, 7, 2, 12, 76, 100, 324]
control_number = 30

h = []
for i in range(len(listt)-1):
    a, b = listt[i], listt[i+1]
    ab = a + b
    if ab < control_number:
        heappush(h, ab)


for _ in range(len(h)):
    print(heappop(h), end=' ') # 9 14 17
print()
```

---

Почти без списков, и с лямбдами!

```
from functools import reduce

solution = sorted(filter(
    lambda x: int(x) < control_number, 
    reduce(
        lambda data,x: {'sums': data['sums'] + (data['prev']+x,) if data['prev'] is not None else tuple(), 'prev': x}, 
        listt, 
        {'sums': tuple(), 'prev': None}
    )['sums']
))

print(' '.join(map(str, solution)))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Короче я не знаю зачем тут нужна lambda)*

```
list_numbers = [10, 7, 2, 12, 76, 100, 324]
CONTROL_NUMBER = 30

def function(numbers: list, control_number: int):
    for x, y in zip(list_numbers, range(len(list_numbers))):
        # print(x, list_number[y-1])
        s = sum((x, list_numbers[y-1]))
        if s < control_number:
            yield s

def main():
    result = sorted(set(function(list_numbers, CONTROL_NUMBER)))
    print(result)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Я не знаю куда там вставить lambda

Comment: `if _` не надо так. Дайте переменной имя)

Comment: Это "Без использования списка и метода списков"?! )

Comment: CrazyElf как могу)

Comment: vp_arth а где это _ используется? я просто видел такой синтаксис

Comment: @Александр подчеркивание традиционно используется как имя переменной, значение которой игнорируется. Если у вас эта переменная используется в условии, то это явно не игнорирование. Использовать ее так не запрещено, но это плохой тон.

Comment: Спасибо теперь всё понятно